Questions about Coding in Pine editor of TradingView
//@version=5
strategy("Price Level Trading Strategy", overlay=true)

// Initialize last trade price and position size
var float lastTradePrice = na
var float avgTradePrice = na
var bool firstTrade = true

// Check current price and make trades
if firstTrade
    strategy.entry("Initial Long", strategy.long, 1)
    lastTradePrice := close
    avgTradePrice := close
    firstTrade := false

// Update average trade price
if strategy.position_size > 0
    avgTradePrice := (avgTradePrice * (strategy.position_size - 1) + close) / strategy.position_size

// Buy 1 only if price drops by 250 from the last trade price
if close <= lastTradePrice - 250
    strategy.entry("Buy More", strategy.long, 1)
    lastTradePrice := close

// Sell 1 only if price rises by 300 from the last trade price
if close >= lastTradePrice + 300
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, 1)
    lastTradePrice := close

// Exit condition for position size > 1
if strategy.position_size > 1
    if close <= avgTradePrice - 250 or close >= avgTradePrice + 300
        strategy.close_all()
        firstTrade := true

It would be nice if someone can solve this coding problem, I try to set a trading strategy for index by:
Initial Entry: Starts with an initial long position.
Average Trade Price: Calculates the average trade price when the position size is greater than 1.
Buy/Sell Conditions: Buys when the price drops by 250 points; sells when it rises by 300 points.
Exit Condition: If the position size is greater than 1 and the price moves 250 points below or 300 points above the average trade price, exits all trades and resets the strategy.
But at the end the strategy tester keep buy 2 or sell 2 in order to entry or exit trade, is there something wrong in the code? Thank you guys!

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

AI-generated code is inconsistent, buggy, and unreliable. Artificial Intelligence is very useful in many aspects, but it encodes Pinescript very poorly (for now...).
Consequently, TradingView and the PineCoders community have decided to not provide support to fix GPT-related code.
